# JBOSS EAP 7 - EJB Client user data

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I have migrated my EJB application from jboss 5.0.1 to JBOSS EAP 7.

I want to pass user data from EJB client to my EJB.

I'm using this code to pass custom attribute to ejb server but it does not work anymore.

Client:

```
public class CustomData extends SimplePrincipal{
String userData1;
public CustomData(String userData1){
this.userData1 = userData1;
}
SecurityClient client = SecurityClientFactory.getSecurityClient();
    client.setSimple(new CustomData("MyData"), credentials.getPass());
    client.login();
```

Server:

```
 @Resource 
 SessionContext ejbCtx;

 Principal data= ejbCtx.getCallerPrincipal();
 data.getName() --- anonymous
```

How to fix it on new JBOSS ?

Comment: I would change the client side to use the standard way of providing login details and then define a proper custom security domain and realm in the server side using your own login module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with this way:

Client:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
 properties.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");
 properties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "MyData");
```

Server:

```
public class MyContainerInterceptor{
@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {

    Connection connection = RemotingContext.getConnection();

    if (connection != null) {
        for (Principal p : connection.getPrincipals()) {
        if (p instanceof UserPrincipal) {
                if (p.getName() != null && !p.getName().startsWith("$"))
                    System.out.println(p.getName()); //MyData will be printed
            }
        }

    }

    return ctx.proceed();
}
```

}

Don't forget to configure container interceptor in jboss-ejb3.xml (not in ejb-jar.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<jee:assembly-descriptor>
    <ci:container-interceptors>
        <jee:interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>package...MyContainerInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </jee:interceptor-binding>
    </ci:container-interceptors>
</jee:assembly-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Create the client side interceptor

This interceptor must implement the org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInterceptor. The interceptor is expected to pass the additional security token through the context data map, which can be obtained via a call to EJBClientInvocationContext.getContextData().

2.Create and configure the server side container interceptor

Container interceptor classes are simple Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs). They use the @javax.annotation.AroundInvoke to mark the method that is invoked during the invocation on the bean.

a.Create the container interceptor

This interceptor retrieves the security authentication token from the context and passes it to the JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service) domain for verification

b. Configure the container interceptor

3.Create the JAAS LoginModule

This custom module performs the authentication using the existing authenticated connection information plus any additional security token.

4. Add the Custom LoginModule to the Chain

You must add the new custom LoginModule to the correct location the chain so that it is invoked in the correct order. In this example, the SaslPlusLoginModule must be chained before the LoginModule that loads the roles with the password-stacking option set.

a.Configure the LoginModule Order using the Management CLI

The following is an example of Management CLI commands that chain the custom SaslPlusLoginModule before the RealmDirect LoginModule that sets the password-stacking option.

b. Configure the LoginModule Order Manually

The following is an example of XML that configures the LoginModule order in the security subsystem of the server configuration file. The custom SaslPlusLoginModule must precede the RealmDirect LoginModule so that it can verify the remote user before the user roles are loaded and the password-stacking option is set.

5. Create the Remote Client

In the following code example, assume the additional-secret.properties file accessed by the JAAS LoginModule

See the link:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Development_Guide/Pass_Additional_Security_For_EJB_Authentication.html